# How can I use HAL_I2C_Transmit?

Tags: stm32, hal

I2C is used and the interrupt method communicates, but when it is done through the polling method, communication is not possible.

Why is this?

Below I have written a simple code.

Interrupt method with communication

```
uint8_t d8_on_tx[] = "D8_LED_ON";

 

HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)SLAVE_ADDRESS, (uint8_t*)d8_on_tx, D8_ON_TX_SIZE);

HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c2, (uint8_t*)rx_data, D8_ON_TX_SIZE);
```

Polling method without communication

```
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)SLAVE_ADDRESS, (uint8_t*)d8_on_tx, D8_ON_TX_SIZE, 20).;

HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c2, (uint8_t*)rx_data, D8_ON_TX_SIZE, 20);
```

I don't know why polling doesn't communicate when the same variable is used.

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious mistakes that you have made, without seeing the full source. But this is what I would do.

```
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)SLAVE_ADDRESS, 
    (uint8_t*)d8_on_tx, D8_ON_TX_SIZE, 20)!=HAL_OK){
       if (HAL_I2C_GetError(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF)
       {
           Error_Handler();

         }
      }
```

This way, you will wait until the transmission completes and if there is an acknowledgement failure you can act on it.

Go to, C:\Users\UserName\STM32Cube\Repository\STM32Cube_FW_F4_Vxx.xx.x
in your computer (with obviously your user name and browse \Projects\STM32-Discovery\Examples\I2C\I2C_TwoBoards_ComPolling\Src

and use refer to that main.c for more info.